# Parallel processing of Timer Tick event with main thread in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, timer

I have this function in which i am trying to call timer event as separate thread, but when i click any button in the page or do any thing in the asp.net page then the timer stop for a sec .

Please help how to run it paralley without the effect of another control in page, as the timer should be running every sec and it should not stop in ui.

```
Thread obj = new Thread(new ThreadStart(timer));
obj.Start();
obj.IsBackground = true;

protected void timer()
{
    Timer1.Interval = 1000;
    Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Timer1_Tick);
    Timer1.Enabled = true;
}

public void TimerProc(object state)
        {
            fromTime = DateTime.Parse(FromTimeTextBox1.Text);
            tillTime = DateTime.Parse(TillTimeTextBox1.Text);
            DateTime currDateTime = System.DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan interval = tillTime - currDateTime;
            if (tillTime <= currDateTime)
            {
                ExamOverPanel1.Visible = true;
                QuestionPanel.Visible = false;
                ListBox2.Visible = false;
                StatusPanel1.Visible = false;
                VisitLaterLabel.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                minLabel.Text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (int)interval.TotalHours, interval.Minutes, interval.Seconds);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way i found is use the Javascript for time display. and run the C# timer in background which will not update UI.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var serverDateTime = new Date('<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>');
        // var dif = serverDateTime - new Date();

        function updateTime() {
            var label = document.getElementById("timelabel");
            if (label) {

                var time = (new Date());
                label.innerHTML = time;
            }
        }
        updateTime();
        window.setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = WindowLoad;
    function WindowLoad(event) {

        ActivateCountDown("CountDownPanel", <%=GetTotalSec() %>);
    }
//GetTotalSec() is c# function which return some value
    </script>

<span id="CountDownPanel"></span> //div to display time
```

All other thing will work on timer1_tick function irrespective of UI.

Answer (score 1):

What class is your Timer1 object?

is it

```
System.Threading.Timer
```

or

```
System.Timers.Timer
```

or

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer
```

or

```
System.Web.UI.Timer
```

? The last two are not really proper timers but arrive on your message queue....

So I'd suggest you check your namespace references - My recommendation in your scenario would be to use the System.Threading.Timer class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using [`System.Web.UI.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx) class, which is used to update an [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) or the whole page periodically. This timer is not so accurate because it entirely runs on the client browser (using JavaScript `window.setTimeout` function) and sends ajax request to the server. If you want to do some operation periodically on the server, you can use `System.Threading.Timer` objects which is invoked in its own thread on the server:

```
public void InitTimer()
{
    System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerProc);
    timer.Change(1000, 1000); // Start after 1 second, repeat every 1 seconds
}

public void TimerProc(object state)
{
    // perform the operation
}
```

But if you want to update the page after performing some operations on the server, you should still use [`System.Web.UI.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx). You can also mix the two, using a thread timer to perform work with high accuracy, and use a web timer to update the page.

Please see the example section of [`System.Web.UI.Timer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx) for a sample usage.

Comment: I implemented that but timer is not running each sec. how to change time each sec?

Comment: @Nishantverma The method `TimerProc` will run every second. No other operation is required. What have you put in `TimerProc`?

Comment: I did debuging and found that its running per sec but not updating the UI.plz check

Comment: I have edited the question and posted TimerProc fucntion please check now.. thanks

Comment: Error 32 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' does not contain a definition for 'BeginInvoke' and no extension method 'BeginInvoke' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Nishantverma Wow! You are on ASP.NET! Web does not work like that! You cannot update the UI from a timer on server! You should use JavaScript an Ajax to poll the server for the changes. Thats a new qeustion!

Comment: so i need to read the c# variable and server time using javascript and then create the timer? do you have any link for that?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i used javascript as suggested by you. I posted the solution as the answer so that other can get benefits. Thanks